# Nmap keeping crashing and popping up the "System Program problem detected", should I worry?

Tags: networking, 20.04, hosts, nmap, arp

[image]

`$ sudo nmap -vv -P -T1 192.168.0.1/24`

Output:

```
>Warning: The -P option is deprecated. Please use -PE
>Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-01-01 18:29 -03
>Initiating ARP Ping Scan at 18:29
>Scanning 255 hosts [1 port/host]
>nmap: Target.cc:503: void Target::stopTimeOutClock(const timeval*): Assertion `htn.toclock_running == true' failed.
>Aborted
```

Comment: I would read the first line of your output; `Warning: The -P option is deprecated. Please use -PE`.  Try using `-PE` instead of `-P` in your command and see if that fixes it.  If it does, then the issue is that you're using a dead function argument, and this is your command at fault (because `-P` is deprecated).

Comment: It's gives the same output.